# I want to use private inner class method (method is public) in junit test case. is it possible?

Tags: java, junit

I have one method in private static inner class. I want to access this method in my junit test case. is it possible and if yes then how?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, we can't help without [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Maybe using reflection

Comment: Why you want to access to a method of a private class from junit?

Comment: I want to test one public method functionality but It accessible only via this private inner class. So I try to do that.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms..

Comment: @user207421:  it is clear that he meant *static member class*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Reflection` to access the `private` methods even if `static` also

Check the below Example to access Private methods using reflection

Example:

```
package demo;

public class Employee {

    private static class EmployeeInnerKlass {
        static void getText() {
            System.out.println("Employee.EmployeeInnerKlass.getText()");
        }
    }
}
class InnerKlass {

    static String getText() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

```
package demo;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class EmployeeTest {

    @Test
    public void accessPrivateMethods() throws Throwable {
        Class<?> klassEmployee = Class.forName("demo.Employee");

        Class<?> EmployeeInnerKlass = klassEmployee.getDeclaredClasses()[0];

        //To get the "EmployeeInnerKlass" declared class in the Employee Class
        Class<?> InnerKlass = Class.forName("demo.InnerKlass");

        Method method = EmployeeInnerKlass.getDeclaredMethod("getText", null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(null, null);

        Method method2 = InnerKlass.getDeclaredMethod("getText", null);
        method2.setAccessible(true);
        method2.invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

I have used TestNG just change it to JUnit and use it.

Comment: Thank  you, Its working for me. But my second concern is I want to pass object as parameter in method e.g:private static class EmployeeInnerKlass {
        static void getText(Customer c) {
            System.out.println("Employee.EmployeeInnerKlass.getText()");
        }
    }  So I have created obj. of customer class and use like:         method_1.invoke(klassEmployee.getDeclaredClasses()[1], event);. but it give error

Comment: @gauripatil As you are using static method, you don't need to use an object to call on that method. So you need to call `method_1.invoke(null, cutomer)`. Can you please post the stackTrace.

Comment: class is static method is not static

Comment: If I use below line then it throws nullpointer exception
        method_1.invoke(null, c);

com.exmaple.privateMethodTestClass > testPrivateMethod() FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.exmaple.privateMethodTestClass.testPrivateMethod(privateMethodTestClass.java:115)

Comment: First invoke the constructor and create object `Constructor<?> constructor = EmployeeInnerKlass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];constructor.setAccessible(true);Object object = constructor.newInstance(null);` then call the `method.invoke(object, customer);`

Comment: is it possible to use same object for inner and outer class?

Comment: @gauripatil you need to use the corresponding object as the parameter or to call the method

Comment: @gauripatil Can you create a chat room and add me and ask it?

Comment: I am not able to create a chat room. I want to create only one object for outerclass and innerclass If I have create new object for inner class then all the outerclass variable I have set not accessible by inner class method because It will crate new object. So I want to refer same object for outer and inner class

Comment: @gauripatil Can you specify with a code example. Edit the question and put an example code

Comment: Hi @gauripatil if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This is the code sample and I want to access this test variable same for all package demo;
public class Employee {

    private boolean test;

    public void display(){
 test=true;
    }
    private static class EmployeeInnerKlass {
        static void getText(Customer c) {
     if(test){
                System.out.println("Employee.EmployeeInnerKlass.getText()");
     }  
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

> I have one method in private static inner class. I want to access this
>   method in my junit test case. is it possible and if yes then how?

The simplest thing you can do is change the accessibility of your static member class from private to package-private access.

This will allow you to access non-private members of your member class from your junit test class (as long as it is given the same package heading).  Making this change will not affect the exported API of your project; clients that access your project package will not see any new methods or members.

When you are satisfied with your tests, you can then simply make your static member class private again.

Comment: I want to do that without changing the accessibility.

Comment: Changing accessibility from private to package-private is simple and it doesn't change your API.  However, if you don't want to, then ... in this case, the conventional answer is that you can't do what you're asking.  Private members can only be accessed from within the same class file.  However, if you want a complex solution, you can use reflection.